# NativeScript with i18next - language pipe is not updating the text

Tags: angular, internationalization, nativescript, i18next

I'm working on a project with NativeScript 6.4.1 and Angular 8.

I want to use the i18next library in my project: https://www.i18next.com/

Here is my sample repository: https://github.com/aubrey-fowler/i18nextTranslationsTest

**Problem: When I change the language, the view is not updating the translation - it's always showing English. Why is it not showing the correct translation?**

I followed to directions here to integrate the library with Angular: https://github.com/Romanchuk/angular-i18next

```
 npm install i18next --save
 npm install angular-i18next --save
```

Here is a code snippet:

```
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(@Inject(I18NEXT_SERVICE) private i18NextService: ITranslationService) {

        this.i18NextService.events.languageChanged.subscribe(lang => {
            // do something
            console.log(' i18NextService ', lang); //this code is called
        });

    }

    changeLang(lang: string) {
        this.i18NextService.changeLanguage(lang);
    }

    addLang(lang: string) {
        this.i18NextService.addResourceBundle(lang, 'translation', {
            "greeting": "Hej"
        }, true, false);
    }

}
```

Here is my view:

```
<ActionBar title="{{ 'greeting' | i18next }}"></ActionBar>

<StackLayout>

    <Label text="{{ 'greeting' | i18next }}"></Label>

    <Button text="en" (tap)="changeLang('en')"></Button>
    <Button text="fr" (tap)="changeLang('fr')"></Button>
    <Button text="nl" (tap)="changeLang('nl')"></Button>

    <Button text="add nl" (tap)="addLang('nl')"></Button>

</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I don't think your current view will update. Try navigating to new page or reloading current, you should see new language strings.

Comment: @Manoj I need the current view to update. How can I do that?

Comment: Use `i18nextEager` instead of `i18next`.

Comment: @Manoj are there any side effects?

Answer (score 0):

I used the i18nextEager pipe instead of the i18next pipe and it worked.

e.g.

```
<ActionBar title="{{ 'greeting' | i18nextEager }}"></ActionBar>

<StackLayout>

    <Label text="{{ 'greeting' | i18nextEager }}"></Label>

    <Button text="en" (tap)="changeLang('en')"></Button>
    <Button text="fr" (tap)="changeLang('fr')"></Button>
    <Button text="nl" (tap)="changeLang('nl')"></Button>

    <Button text="add nl" (tap)="addLang('nl')"></Button>

</StackLayout>
```

Also, you can add languages like this method:

```
addLang() {

    this.i18NextService.addResourceBundle('nl', 'translation', {
        "greeting": "Hej"
    }, true, true);

    console.log(this.i18NextService.languages);
}
```